# Absolutely continuous then $\nu(A)>0 \Rightarrow \mu(A)>0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{M})$ be a measurable space and $\nu,\mu:\mathcal{M} \to \mathbb{R}$ be additive set functions. I would like to prove or disprove that if $\nu$ is absolutely continuous in terms of $\mu$, then for any $A\in\mathcal{M}$, $\nu(A)>0 \Rightarrow \mu(A)>0$ holds.

**What I did:**

So firstly, I tried to write down definitions.

**Def 1:** Let $\Phi: \mathcal{M} \to \mathbb{R}$ be an additive set function. we define

$\Phi^+(E) := \sup_{A\subset E}\Phi(A)$

$\Phi^-(E) := (-\Phi)^+(E)$

$|\Phi|(E) := \Phi^+(E)+\Phi^{-}(E)$

**Def 2:** Let $\nu,\mu:\mathcal{M} \to \mathbb{R}$ be additive set functions. $\nu$ is said to be absolutely continuous in terms of $\mu$ if $|\mu|(E)=0 \Rightarrow |\nu|(E)=0$ holds for all $E\in\mathcal{M}$.

Note that those definitions came from different sources, so something may be inconsistent. Feel free to correct them if something is wrong.

After I wrote down the definitions, I tried to prove it by contradiction: that is, I first assumed there exists $A\in \mathcal{M}$ such that $\nu(A)>0$ but $\mu(A)\leq 0$. However, I was unsuccessful in this and lost now.

Comment: Depending on the context (your setup and definitions), I would believe the implication $\nu(A) > 0 \Rightarrow \mu(A) > 0$ is either a definition of absolute continuity, or is false.

Comment: What if $\nu = -\mu$?

Comment: @Bungo Ah, so in that case $\mu^{+}(E)=\nu^{-}(E)$ and $\mu^{-}(E)=\nu^{+}(E)$, so $|\mu|=|\nu|$ and $\nu$ is absolutely continuous, but the proposition does not hold. Thanks.

Comment: @Bungo I will accept if you would like to make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\nu$ be any additive set function that satisfies $\nu(A) > 0$ for some $A \in \mathcal M$. Let $\mu = -\nu$. Then $\nu^+ = \mu^-$ and $\nu^- = \mu^+$, which means that
$$|\nu| = \nu^+ + \nu^- = \mu^- + \mu^+ = |\mu|.$$
This shows that $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$ (and vice versa). However, if $A$ is any set for which $\nu(A) > 0$, then by definition $\mu(A) < 0$, so this is a counterexample to the claim.